# How to record typing in C# (keyListener)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to write a simple text to speech program.

First, I want to make the program play only the written symbol.  For example, if I type 'a' I want the program to say 'a' (I have recorded all of them), so when I type a word, it should spell it.

However, I am a beginner in C# and .Net and don't how to make the program understand the text I type.  For example, in java I heard that there is a keyListener class, but I don't know which class should I use.  I looked on MSDN but couldn't find it.

Which class or function should I use to listen to typed keys?

Comment: Will you be using WinForms or WPF? A Console Application maybe? Or a web app? Silverlight? Because the answer will depend on your choice of technology.

Comment: how would you like to play the sound? every key you press a sound will appear, or when done typing, the word will be pronounced (basesd on individual letters)

Comment: i am going to do both, but first i will do the "every key pressed sound" and then i will do for the whole words. but the word won't be based on individual letters. i am doing this program not for english language, that's why it is much easier to do it on whole words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose you are planning to use Windows Forms to achieve this.
The solution would be pretty simple. These events include MouseDown, MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseEnter, MouseLeave, MouseHover, KeyPress, KeyDown, and KeyUp. Each control has these events exposed. You just need to subscribe to it.

Please refer to this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx

There would be a little bit of logic to find whether a complete word has been typed or not. A simple soultion would be , when space has been pressed, you can assume a word has been completed. Its very crude logic, as the user may have typed in wrong spelling and want hit backspace and correct the spelling. You may want to add lag to it.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Visual Studio like every other C# developer here is a more detailed code example:

1. Create a Windows Form and go to the [Design].
2. Select its properties (RMB=>properties), navigate to Events and double click LMB on `KeyDown`
3. VS will create and bind the event for you
4. Handle the `KeyEventArgs` depending on its value.

Example:

```
private void NewDialog_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyData)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                {
                    MethodToOutputSound(AEnum);
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.B:
                {
                    MethodToOutputSound(BEnum);
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.F11:
                {
                    DifferentMethod();
                    break;
                }
            case Keys.Escape:
                {
                    this.Close();
                    break;
                }
            default:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
}
```

Or use a lot of `if`s

```
 private void NewDialog_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
        if(e.KeyData == Keys.A)
        {
            MethodToOutputSound(AEnum);
        }

        if(e.KeyData == Keys.B)
        {
            MethodToOutputSound(BEnum);
        }
        ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows Form with a TextBox in it. Handle the KeyPress event - that will give you the actual character that the user types. KeyDown and KeyUp won't help you.

You need to check the `KeyChar` property. Like this:

```
void MyEventHandler(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    // Do stuff depending on the value of e.KeyChar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string word = textBox1.Text;
        foreach (char i in word)
        {
            switch (i)
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A': { // play sound a

                    break;
                }
                default:
                    {
                        // play no sound
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```