# Determine number of characters entered into textbox with C#

Tags: c#, string, text, textbox, int

Hi I was wanting to display the number of characters entered into a textbox and I want it to update as I type how can I go about this?

Here is what I have:

```
int kk = textBox1.MaxLength;
int jj = //This is what I need to know.
string lol = jj.ToString() + "/" + kk.ToString();
label2.Text = lol;
```

Comment: You should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399697/how-to-record-typing-in-c-sharp-keylistener

Comment: You should give your variables decent names

Comment: I know these were examples I usually name them one of my pets names lol

Comment: BlackBear: You should give decent answers. After all, it doesn't matter what names you give your variables. At least if you're not a professional programmer working with other people.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

How about

```
int jj = textBox1.Text.Length;
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: @John_Dong: Well it's a matter of thinking one step removed - you want to know the number of characters in the text of the text box, so you need to know a) how to get the number of characters in a string, and b) the value of a textbox as a string.

Comment: Do you by any chance also know how to read bytes from a file from a min and max hex offset and convert it to a string?

Comment: @John_Dong: Open a stream (e.g. File.Open). Seek using the Position property. Read the data you want, looping round and using the result of Stream.Read each time. Use `Encoding` to convert the bytes into text.

Answer (score 2):

The text of the text box will be a string, so it has a `Length` property, i.e.:

```
textBox1.Text.Length
```

Comment: I'd have thought. Jon Skeet seems to think so too, and he's a man who knows stuff! (so if I'm wrong, I'm in good company :))

Comment: If you want a reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`TextBoxobject.Text.Length` will give you the length of textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the OnTextChanged event of the Textbox on the client side in Javascript and compute the increment from.

Comment: That's what I did but I set the test on load to "0/1020" and then it changes the min value every time the text gets changed.